# Placing a global HTTP requests per second limit

Tags: c#, multithreading, httprequest

due to server limitations, I cannot make more than one requests per 3 second, I am using `Thread.Sleep()` to limit the number of requests I can make.  Is there a better way without having to pause the thread?  Thanks.

```
static void main(string[] args)
{
    // getids
    List<string> requestIds = GetMyRequestIds();

    foreach(string requestId in requestIds)
    {
        Thread.Sleep(3000);

        // one request for each Id
        result = FetchStatus(requestId);
    }

}

public Dictionary<string, object> FetchStatus(string requestId)
{
    // build http request and query the server
    // ... requestId... http... etc... read to end
    return results;
}
```

Comment: This is your code so you're going to have to control how often and/or how many requests you send. There isn't an "overlord" process that will throttle the requests for you.

Answer (score 0):

If your limitation is just one request per 3 seconds you could set up a timer which fires a callback every 3 seconds. As this is executed in a separate thread, it is possible that two long running requests execute simultaneously.

[System.Threading.Timer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.threading.timer%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)